# Finding the eigenvalues when $c$ is unknown

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given that $$A=\begin{bmatrix} \ 0 & 1 & 0 \\-c & c+1 & 0 \\1 & 1 &-1\end{bmatrix},$$
determine the eigenvalues of $A$.

I have found that  $\lambda^3-c\lambda^2-\lambda-c=0 $. How can I continue from here?

Comment: …hmm…have you noticed that (1,1,1) is an eigenvector? Now you should be able to find an eigenvalue, and then you can factor the characteristic polynomial, and then factor the resulting quadratic in the usual manner…(I found the eigenvector just by staring at the matrix and guessing a little, in case this seems like magic)

Comment: A general way that can be used to find the eigenvalues of a square matrix is to use elementary row (column) operations on it to transform it into a triangular matrix and then the elements on the principal diagonal will be the eigenvalues. This works because similar matrices preserve eigenvalues and eigenvalues of a triangular matrix are its diagonal elements.

Comment: nope i did not notice that , it seem like i am still unfamiliar with eigenvector & eigenvalue.. still in the mid of learning :P  currently doing textbook question

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the characteristic polynomial along the last column:
$$
\det(\lambda I-A_c)=
\det\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & -1 & 0 \\
c & \lambda - c - 1 & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & \lambda + 1
\end{bmatrix}=
(\lambda+1)\det\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & -1 \\
c & \lambda - c - 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & -1 \\
c & \lambda - c - 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\lambda^2-(c+1)\lambda+c=
(\lambda-c)(\lambda-1)
$$
so we finally get
$$
\det(\lambda I-A_c)=(\lambda+1)(\lambda-c)(\lambda-1)
$$
The long version is
$$
\det(\lambda I-A_c)=\lambda^3-c\lambda^2-\lambda+c
$$
and you have a wrong constant term.

I don't know where your mistake was; if you used Sarrus' rule, be careful with it: expanding with respect to a row or column that only has a nonzero coefficient is better.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong characteristic polynomial.
\begin{align}\det(A-\lambda I) & =-(\lambda(\lambda-c-1)+c)(\lambda+1)=-(\lambda^2-(c+1)\lambda+c)(\lambda+1)\\ &= -(\lambda-c)(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1).\end{align}

Alternatively : as pointed out in the comments, $(1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ (because the sum of the elemens in every line is $1$), and $(0,0,1)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$. Since $\det A=-c$ is the product of the eigenvalues and $\operatorname{tr}(A)=c$ is their sum, the last eigenvalue must be $c$.

Comment: noted :) i realize that i did wrongly..